# Why does my program crash when I add a text field?

Tags: flutter

My code is very simple:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title:"title", home: Scaffold(body: TextField()));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

No matter how I try to include the text field, the program just crushes.
I'm compiling to web, maybe that's related to the problem?

Edit: So that's awkward. But the code seems to work perfectly fine now...
Though the following code still crashes after adding the text field:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title:"title", home: Scaffold(body:
      Row(children: [
        Column(children: [
          TextField()
        ])
      ]
    )));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it on a simulator?

Comment: Could you please paste your crash log here. I noticed that no error in your code.

Comment: It says:

Assertion failed:
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4e4cf NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT"

The relevant error-causing widget was
TextField

But I have no idea what to do about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens, because there is no width constraint to the TextField.

In your case, wrapping the column in an `Expanded` widget should fix the problem.

See the flutter documentation for more info and solutions to this problem: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/common-errors#an-inputdecoratorcannot-have-an-unbounded-width